# what does a backslash followed by grep mean?

Tags: bash, grep

I am following an impatient way of learning and working with bash scripts,
in [this link](http://www.servercobra.com/bash-check-if-package-is-installed.html) I saw a line like this:

```
INSTALLED=$(dpkg -l \grep $1)
```

can you tell me what \grep means?

thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure that should be `INSTALLED=$(dpkg -l | \grep $1)` (note the pipe before `\grep`). As written, `\grep` is passed to `dpkg` as an argument, which doesn't make any sense...

Comment: @GordonDavisson huh! No wonder it wasn't working. Anyways, since the topic of questions is something else and that line it is a copy/paste from the given link, let's keep it that way. thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\grep` means execute `system default grep` from `/bin/grep` OR `/usr/bin/grep` **ignoring all local environment aliases you may have set up** for `grep`.

- You can put backslash before any BASH command to ignore aliases with the same name.

**Example:**

```
> alias grep=date
> grep
Thu Nov 28 22:49:57 EST 2013
> \grep
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try `grep --help' for more information.
```